# Is there a way to acces external .blend file's data with python script?

Tags: scripting, python

I'm writing an addon to **parse a directory** (and its sub-dirs) to write an **XML** file which describe the tree-structure of the assets contained in that directory.
At the moment, my standalone script works pretty well.

The fact is, I need to add some info to the XML, like the **dependencies** (linked libraries) of each .blend file the script found.

I found a way to do this (outside blender), with the module "pyblenderfile" : http://code.google.com/p/pyblenderfile/

The principle of this module is to **open a .blend and get all its data**. But it's pretty long and often buggy on large .blend files. Especially since it's included in a `for ...` loop!

So I wonder if there is a utility function or method into Blender API, to access other .blend files data (without having to `wm.open()` them) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no data API for the .blend file format.

However, it sounds like you're trying to make a tool similar to [Blender-Aid](http://www.atmind.nl/?p=47) ([code is here](https://code.google.com/p/blender-aid/)). Perhaps that's better place to start.

Note that `blendfile.py` from Blender-Aid can be used as a standalone blend file reader.

Comment: Note that I've updated `blendfile.py` for use in BlenderAssetManager,  https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAM/browse/master/bam/blend/blendfile.py

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can load in blend file data without opening the blend file using the [library API](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries).

Though this is intended for linking in data, you can use it to get data-blocks from a blend file. However it may not be a solution for you since you can **only list the data-block names**.

Optionally you could link the data, then remove it if you wanted to find out more about the data-blocks.

*Note, I realize that [`blendfile.py`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAM/browse/master/bam/blend/blendfile.py) may prove a better solution regarding the use case described in the question, but adding this answer for completeness, others who read this question may find the library method useful.*

Comment: Thanks @ideasman42, the `blendfile.py` script did the job pretty well (I had a little issue with "string length" while reading blocks, but I found a workaround and everything works perfect)

Comment: @Polosson, I noticed string length needed changes too, would be good to get these updated committed back to the original repo.

Comment: well, I made a very small modif in the `blendfile.py`... Just increased the range (line 122), up to 1250. It prevent the use of `FindBlendFileBlocksWithCode()`, then `block.Get()` to raise the `list index out of range` exception, but it return some strange strings, like `link1.blendnk1.blend`, instead of `link1.blend`. So my workaround was to split the string to only get the first `:.blend` string! Not very neat but it works. :D

Comment: I've since made an updated `blendfile.py`, with quite a few changes/optimizations - linked in the answer.