# Translate blend file to python

Tags: blend-files

How can I get equivalent python code for a created blend file from blender. I want to generate java code for corresponding python code of a blender. I am unable to get python code of blender file either inside or outside the blender.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Do you want python code that generates the vertices and faces of a model in your .blend file? Blender has a python API, but internally it is programmed in C. And the abstract data structures Blender uses internally can not be exported directly as a python script.

Comment: Question is not a duplicate, but is related to: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2410

Comment: You could elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do. Probably better solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

Blender has no facility to write a `.blend` file as a series of Python instructions.

For limited uses you could write your own script (Its been done before for rigify armatures for eg), but for the entire blend file this becomes a large task.