# How to delete scene-datablock without opening it?

Tags: blend-files, scene

I appended a relatively big scene (~400mb) to a .blend file. Unfortunately, I cannot open the scene. If I try to do, blender freezes. 
So I need to delete that scene again without opening it. Is there any possibility using the internal (or external?) file browser? Or a work-around?

Thanks and greetings,
OldPowel

Comment: Have you tried opening a new file and appending the scenes you want from old file?  Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/is-there-a-way-to-acces-external-blend-files-data-with-python-script.  Could check your backup (tmp) files to see if there is a pre-append version. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/how-to-recover-overwritten-files-in-blender

Comment: Well, that was too obvious to see it. Should work perfectly, thank you!