# Is there any way to retain the name of layers from a 2.79 file when opened in 2.8+?

Tags: collections, layers

I have a lot of Blender files created in 2.79 which all use the Layer Manager add-on to help organize the scenes. It lets you custom name each layer. When opening these files in 2.8+, the layers are converted to the new collections, but the custom layer names are discarded and each collection is named after the layer's number instead. Is there any way to retain the layer name information? I couldn't find anything about this and I'm guessing it's not going to work since Layer Manager is an add-on rather than a built in feature of 2.79. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Based on the answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/is-there-a-way-to-acces-external-blend-files-data-with-python-script It _seems_ that this is only possible with a source code modification.

Comment: Bummer, but expected. Thanks for the link.